# Java 8 date-time parsing with optional 2-4 year components

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I would like to parse LocalDate objects from various date strings. All strings already have the format dd-MM-yy or dd-MM-yyyy. In the first case the base year should be prepended with 19 instead of 20.

I have this code but I can't get it working. What am I doing wrong?

```
        public static LocalDate parseDateString(String date) {
            DateTimeFormatter optionalFullYearParser = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd-MM-yy][dd-MM-yyyy]");
            DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendOptional(optionalFullYearParser)
                    .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 4, 1900)
                    .toFormatter(new Locale ("nl","NL"));

            return java.time.LocalDate.parse(date,parser);
        }

        System.out.println(parseDateString("11-10-56").toString());
        System.out.println(parseDateString("11-10-1956").toString());
        System.out.println(parseDateString("08-05-51").toString());
```

When I run this code it throws an Exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '11-10-56' could not be parsed at index 8
>       ...

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You’re over-complicating it. See how simple it is in my answer to the linked original question. The trick is to have `yyyy` *before* `yy`, or it will parse the first two of the four digits as a two digit year and then get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for 2 formatter objects to do this, and you shouldn't include the year part in the pattern text when you then use `appendValueReduced` to add the year part.

```
public static LocalDate parseDateString(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("dd-MM-")
            .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 4, 1900)
            .toFormatter(Locale.forLanguageTag("nl-NL"));
    return java.time.LocalDate.parse(date, parser);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(parseDateString("11-10-56").toString());
System.out.println(parseDateString("11-10-1956").toString());
System.out.println(parseDateString("08-05-51").toString());
```

*Output*

```
1956-10-11
1956-10-11
1951-05-08
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works!